# Angular Autocomplete: value y displaywith observables

Tags: angular, autocompletar, observable

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que integra Angular (frontend) y Yii2 (backend). Hasta ahora no tuve grandes dificultades excepto por las últimas semanas que me he estancado con un problema de **Angular Material**. Estuve explorando muchas soluciones en Internet, pero hasta ahora no tuve suerte.

Estoy tratando de crear un formulario de carga que tiene alrededor de **10 elementos Autocomplete** de Angular Material. La información la recopilo desde un Servicio Angular como observable. La misma llega por API Rest desde el backend. En cada elemento Autocomplete muestro con facilidad las opciones a elegir, pero el problema radica cuando intento obtener únicamente el **ID del objeto** (para una posterior alta). Si bien lo obtengo, la propiedad **DisplayWith** me devuelve el valor del ID cuando en realidad quiero que me devuelva todo el objeto así puedo volver a visualizar la opción seleccionada por el usuario, por ejemplo, nombre y apellido.

En la web encontré como solucionar este problema con arreglos de objetos o simples arreglos, pero **no sé cómo solucionarlo utilizando observables**. Capaz estoy encarando mal toda la situación. Estuve leyendo, entre muchos otros, [este aporte](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4863) pero desafortunadamente no encontré la solución.
Desde ya muchas gracias y cualquier ayuda será muy apreciable.

Este es mi código, muestro el ejemplo con un único elemento autocomplete.

**Angular componente**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, debounceTime, switchMap, map, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { DedicacionI } from '../../../models/dedicacion.interface'
import { DedicacionesService } from 'src/app/services/dedicaciones.service';

export class DocenteAltaComponent implements OnInit {
 
  myForm = new FormGroup()

  myControlDedicaciones = new FormControl();
  dedicacionesList: Observable<DedicacionI[]>;
  filteredOptionsDedicaciones: Observable<DedicacionI[]>;

  constructor (
    public fb:FormBuilder,

    private dedicaciones:DedicacionesService,
    ) 
    
    { 

      this._getDedicacionesData();

      this.filteredOptionsDedicaciones = this.myControlDedicaciones.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(val => {
          return this._filterDedicaciones(val || '')
        })
      )
    }
    
  private _getDedicacionesData():void {
    this.dedicacionesList = this.dedicaciones.getDedicaciones();
  }

  private _filterDedicaciones(val: string) {
    return this.dedicacionesList.pipe(
      map(response => response.filter(option => {
        let aux = option.denominacion.toString();
        return aux.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0
      }))
    )
  }

  public displayDedicacion (dedicacionSel): string {
    if (dedicacionSel != null){
      return dedicacionSel.denominacion + " (" + dedicacionSel.codigo + ")";
    }else{
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

**Angular html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">

    <!-- Dedicaciones -->
    <p>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text"
            placeholder="Dedicación"
            aria-label="Number"
            matInput
            [formControl]="myControlDedicaciones"
            [matAutocomplete]="autoDededicacion">
            <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoDededicacion="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayDedicacion">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptionsDedicaciones | async" [value]="option">
                <p>{{option.denominacion}} ({{option.codigo}}) </p>
                                
            </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <!-- /.Dedicaciones -->

</form>
```

**Angular servicio**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DedicacionI } from '../models/dedicacion.interface';

@Injectable()

export class DedicacionesService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getDedicaciones() {

    return this.http.get<DedicacionI[]>("http://localhost/yii2-tests/rest/web/index.php/v1/dedicaciones")
          
  }

}
```

Comment: Estoy intentando entender el código y supongo que al intentar simplificarlo para crear un [mcve] (bien por tu parte) se te han quedado algunas cosas colgando: ¿usas el FormBuilder para crear tu formulario? En el código de tu ejemplo parece no usarse.

Comment: Pablo, gracias por responder, evidentemente me olvidé de activar las notificaciones por e-mail. Sí, lo estoy utilizando. Pero como mencionas, consideré omitirlo porque mi problema radica en que no puedo devolver como value el id y al mismo tiempo mostrar (displayWith) otras propiedades del objeto. Voy a intentar seguir el enlace que me recomendas para mejorar la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve este mismo problema, lo solucioné agregando el atributo optionSelected a la etiqueta mat-autocomplete, quité el formControl del html y lo manejo desde el componente

Ejemplo Html:

```
<mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="onSelectionChange($event)" >
```

Ej Componente:

```
onSelectionChange(event: any){
    console.log('onSelectionChange called', event.option.value.id);
    this.form.patchValue({
      option_id: event.option.value.id,
    })
  }
```